# Getting Bound method error when calling function from another class

Tags: python

So i have a class called read that is full of Def, im trying to call one of them and i get a 'Bound method' error, what do you think.

```
from ExcelRead import Read

t = Read()
L = t.other
print L

def Other():
   User = []
   Excel = []
   lst = OpenExcel()
   User = OpenFile("whatever.txt")
   for item in lst:
       Excel.append(str(item.value))
   Excel = [line.strip() for line in Excel]
   Differ = comp(User, Excel)
   print Differ
```

This is calling other functions

Where other is the name of the function i want to call, this function does return a value. thanks for your help

Comment: is `other()` actually in a class?

Comment: What is a "Bound method error"? I've never seen such a thing. Copy and paste the actual error message and traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting any error at all here. You're simply printing the function, which is indeed bound.

As with any other function in Python, if you want to call it, you need to use parentheses:

```
L = t.other()
print L
```

Comment: When i add the parentheses i get Other takes no arguments but given 1

Comment: As you can see im not giving it anything but for some reason it thinks i am

Comment: You should show the definition. Don't forget Python object methods are always automatically passed the `self` argument.

Comment: Ok i add the Other() method

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be in a class at all. Where is the `self` argument that all methods must have?